# Vanilla javascript function to type only numbers not working if not called inline

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have found this function aimed to block the typing of characters that are not numbers:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I call it like so:  `<input class="onlynumbers" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumber(this);" >` it works.

If I write something like:

```
var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.onlynumbers');
for (var i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
    clickMe[i].addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {

        isNumber(event);

    }, false);
}
```

it does not. I can still type in letters. And I cannot figure out the reason. 
Can you please help me with that? Hint: I cannot use JQUERY.

Comment: Why not use `<input type="number" />`?

Comment: Also, you don't `return` in that event listener. You need `return isNumber(event)` - same as the inline one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @VLAZ suggested, using `type="number"` is a better solution.

However, to fix your code - if the character is not a number use `event.preventDefault()` to block the letter insertion:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var clickMe = document.querySelectorAll('.onlynumbers');

for (var i = 0; i < clickMe.length; i++) {
  clickMe[i].addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if(!isNumber(event)) event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<input class="onlynumbers" type="text">
```